# Can the read() function lead to overflow?

Tags: c

If the size of a buffer array is 100 and I read 100 bytes from a file using `read()`, can there be a possibility of overflow as there is no null terminating byte? I am reading from a file and then writing to standard output.

```
int incoming_bytes = read(filedes, buffer, 100);
write(1, buffer, incoming_bytes);
```

Comment: `read()` will not overflow, but be very careful with what you do with that buffer

Comment: What do you mean by be careful? If I use the write function to write from the buffer, could I write more than what is inside the buffer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`read()` and `write()` don't work with strings, but with buffers, and as such they don't need to know their contents, just their size.

As long as you only use the buffer to `write` into `stdout`, you won't have any overrun problems.

`'\0'` is only needed for strings.

The problem may come if you later treat that buffer as a string.  In that case, you will most probably overrun it.

Comment: Ok. So as I have written my code where I write from the buffer, there shouldn't be an issue since I will just write whatever is in the buffer?

Comment: (so long as the original buffer was sufficiently sized to hold the contents of the `read` to begin with -- otherwise you have already written beyond the bounds of your original array invoking Undefined Behavior) The other problem your question asks, in a round about way related to the *nul-terminating* character and exceeding the bounds of buffer, will occur if you pass buffer to any function expecting a *string*. So long as you keep the *array/string* limitations in mind, you shouldn't experience any problems using either. Your 100 sized buffer, 100 bytes read is fine.